# What is this ornamental tree with coarsely serrated leaves?

Tags: identification, trees, ornamental-plant

All I know is that the tree is small (2m), is grafted at 1m, has (or can be pruned into) 'globosum' habit, and have such leaves:

[image]

Another picture: (the trees in question are in the group in the middle):

[image]

Can you guess the species name or at least point me towards its genus until I can upload pictures for this tree's other characteristics?

---

New photos, sunny April day:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some leaves have most unusual 'nipples', never saw such leaves before.

Comment: "unusual leaves"? To me they seems very similar to oaks, so common form.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi oak? Which kind do you have in mind?

Comment: “Oak-like” is not what I would think of when looking at your photo. I’d expect much deeper and larger lobes: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_leaf_morphology#/media/File%3ALeaf_morphology.svg

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak

Comment: Sorry to put it so bluntly, but from the little we can see, I see nothing super unusual about the leaves. For a good id we’d need one full leaf, ideally top and bottom and some scale. And if you mean the color, I guess we are looking at autumn discoloration? I can’t blame @GiacomoCatenazzi for not answering.

Comment: As  already suggested, Oak of some variety. Possibly Quercus macranthera, (persian oak) but frankly, the photo's not much use for ID purposes - not enough visible foliage, no image of trunk or overall growth habit, too dark.

Comment: @Bamboo Quercus macranthera leaves are more deeply serrated...

Comment: “Nothing special” as in “no truly distinctive feature that gives a good clue”. And you were the one who originally wrote “unusual”, which @GiacomoCatenazzi probably responded to. I realize that you don’t have more photos, I just wanted to point out that what you have might be not enough for a good id.

Comment: @VividD: as Stephie wrote, nothing really special or distinctive on the leaves. I find common in some oaks. So I doesn't mean it is a common tree. On the contrary, not being a distinctive leave, it makes difficult to identify the species.

Comment: And I confirm that sometime identification keys require photos of different periods to be identified (springs and late leaves, or more often [female] flowers and leaves, which on some trees are not found on the same periods).  To help, closeup to buds, trunk and branches could help to find if it is a oak.  But at this stage an exact identification is not possibles (and it is is a oak: oaks are sometime difficult also in summers: many intermediate cases)

Comment: Just being able to see only three entire leaves, and one of those sideways on, the other chopped off at the edge of the photo, means its impossible to say whether its Persian Oak or anything else for sure - not having a crystal ball, its the best educated guess I can make anyway

Comment: @Giacomo New photos...

Comment: @Bamboo New photos...

Comment: @Stephie New photos...

Comment: @VividD nice! The “nipples” are (insect) galls - see: https://www.extension.umn.edu/garden/insects/find/insect-and-mite-galls/

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be Hornbeam (Carpinus betulus), complete with gall nipples, as Stephie says. Image here https://www.bowhayestrees.co.uk/hornbeam.html

Comment: too few veins to be Carpinus betulus (on my zone, we use number of veins to distinguish it from Ostrya carpinifolia. I'm going to Morus (but I need to think it, or check some flora, no time now)

Comment: @vividd: Could you check again the plant? If it is Carpinus betulus, now it should have the catkins.

Comment: BTW Carpinus seems a better match then Morus. But still.... not convinced (maybe some Alnus, which could have a very small habit)